# Publicly available Rest API End points

Tags: rest, informatica-powercenter

I have a scenario where I want to push a file from UNIX server to Rest API end point. I am planning to use HTTP transformation in Informatica for that. But I would like test the possibility of pushing a file to publicly available Rest API End point. But I couldn't find any publicly available Rest API end points which accepts a file. Can someone help me. Appreciate your help!!

I tried to search for publicly available Rest API end point to push a file. But I couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: Finding public services is out of scope for stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Give those two a try:

- https://mockapi.io
- https://beeceptor.com

I love the latter - it's great! I have not tried uploading files, though, and I'm not sure what is it you need or try to achieve.